# how to add attribute with value in td tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one table that has 2 row and 3 column. I want add 2 attribute to any td that detect place it. (these attributes are `col` & `row` that show column and row for any tds.)

this is my code :

```
<table id="tab">
  <tr id="rows">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="rows" style="top:50px">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I want use loop that add 2 attribute in it any level for any td and at last I want to get this code but I cannot do it:

```
<table id="tab">
  <tr id="rows">
    <td col="1" row="1"></td>
    <td col="2" row="1"></td>
    <td col="3" row="1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="rows" style="top:50px">
    <td col="1" row="2"></td>
    <td col="2" row="2"></td>
    <td col="3" row="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you having problems with? What isn't working?

Comment: my problem is I don't know how add attr to tag

Comment: `$(elem).attr('foo', 'bar')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by this jQuery:

```
$("#tab tr td").each(function(){
    $(this)
        .attr("col", $(this).index() + 1)
        .attr("row", $(this).parent().index() + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[documentation will help](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('selector').attr('name', 'value');
```